# Can not understand how Spark let python run at Yarn? How does the ProcessBuilder deal with zip file?

Tags: java, python, scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

The step is :

1.package all the python files into the pyspark.zip when building Spark.

2.spark-submit to Yarn it distributed the pyspark.zip to all the machine.

3.Spark Worker find the pyspark.zip and process the python file in it.

But the code [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/api/python/PythonWorkerFactory.scala#L117) and [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/api/python/PythonWorkerFactory.scala#L53) shows that it only put the zip files' path into ProcessBuilder's environment. And I haven't find the code that unzip pyspark.zip .

So I'm wondering how does ProcessBuilder unzip the pyspark.zip ?
Or how does Spark Worker run the python files in pyspark.zip ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact if you type `python -h`, it will show

```
Other environment variables:
PYTHONPATH   : ':'-separated list of directories prefixed to the default module search path.  The result is sys.path.
```

And ProcessBuilder could use the zip without unzip it.

Also,A zip file could be import in Python directly, you don’t need to unzip it.

```
List commands = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
commands.add("python");
commands.add("-m");
commands.add("test");//test.py in test.zip
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
pb.command(commands);
Map workerEnv = pb.environment();
workerEnv.put("PYTHONPATH", "/path/to/test.zip");
Process worker = pb.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

YARN has mechanisms for auto-unbundling: JAR, ZIP, and TGZ files. There is a short discussion about it [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WritingYarnApplications.html#How_can_I_distribute_my_applications_jars_to_all_of_the_nodes_in_the_YARN_cluster_that_need_it) you can also look at the full [API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/records/LocalResource.html)